How to add mediaItem in queue and play in flutter
i am using audio_service
and i want to add to mediaItem in queue then i want to play song one by one
_setYtLInk() async {
    for (var ytid in ytlinks) {
      var ytExplode = yt.YoutubeExplode();
      var video = await ytExplode.videos.streamsClient.getManifest(ytid);
      var meta = await ytExplode.videos.get(ytid);

      var audioStreamInfo = video.audioOnly.withHighestBitrate();

      var item = MediaItem(
        id: audioStreamInfo.url.toString(),
        album: 'Unknown',
        title: meta.title,
        artist: 'Unknown',
        duration: meta.duration,
        artUri: Uri.parse('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/${ytid}/hqdefault.jpg'),
      );

      await _audioService.addQueueItem(item).then((_) {}).catchError((error) {
        // check error
      });
    }

   __audioService.play();
  }

but its not playing please help me
